# Background images temporary solution to images in responsive web design?

Tags: responsive-design

So I realize one of the big problems currently in responsive web design is that you download large images when they might not be needed, like on a phone-causing a serious performance hit-which you also get to an extent with conditional loading with JS; so my question is couldn't I just load most of my images as background images within media queries and overcome this problem until something better comes around? Example:

```
/* base styles */
 @media all and (min-width: 53.75em) {
 header .inner{
 background: url(‘../images/football_bg.png’) bottom right
no-repeat;
}
```

Obviously this is completely non semantic, but could solve the performance issues right?

Comment: width should be in px.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll look in to adaptive images further.. And glad to know this could work too (as a rag-tag bandaid method and semantics aside).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using media queries and background images works like a charm, so if it's a good fit for your project then by all means use it.

Using background images isn't always possible though.

If this is the case, one option is [Adaptive Images](http://adaptive-images.com), which will serve different sized images based on the visitor's viewport. It's easy enough to retro-fit to an existing site and check if it will work for you.

Another possiblity if you use [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com) is that they've just released something similar which looks really interesting: [Interchange](http://zurb.com/playground/foundation-interchange)

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You could look into using Adaptive Images if you really care about semantics: http://adaptive-images.com/
Also here is a good article about solutions for images and responsive design. http://css-tricks.com/which-responsive-images-solution-should-you-use/